# using parallel's parLapply: unable to access variables within parallel code

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I recently got a computer with several cores and am learning to use parallel computing.  I'm fairly proficient with `lapply` and was told `parLapply` works very similarly.  I'm not operating it correctly though.  It seems I have to explicitly put everything inside the `parLapply` to make it work (that is functions to be use, variables etc.).  With `lapply` it reads from the parent environment and `parLapply` does not seem to do this.  So in my example below I could make everything work by placing all info inside `parLapply` but if I use this inside a user defined function I can't explicitly put `text.var` inside of `parLapply`.

```
library(parallel)
text.var <- rep("I like cake and ice cream so much!", 20)
ntv <- length(text.var)
gc.rate <- 10

pos <-  function(i) {
    paste(sapply(strsplit(tolower(i), " "), nchar), collapse=" | ")
}

lapply(seq_len(ntv), function(i) {
        x <- pos(text.var[i])
        if (i%%gc.rate==0) gc()
        return(x)
    }

)

#doesn't work
cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", 4))
parLapply(cl, seq_len(ntv), function(i) {
        x <- pos(text.var[i])
        if (i%%gc.rate==0) gc()
        return(x)
    }

)

#does work but have to specify all the stuff inside parLapply
cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", 4))
parLapply(cl, seq_len(ntv), function(i) {
        ######stuff I have to put inside parLapply##########
        text.var <- rep("I like cake and ice cream so much!", 20)
        ntv <- length(text.var)
        gc.rate <- 10
        pos <-  function(i) {
            paste(sapply(strsplit(tolower(i), " "), nchar), collapse=" | ")
        }
        ######stuff I have to put inside parLapply##########
        x <- pos(text.var[i])
        if (i%%gc.rate==0) gc()
        return(x)
    }
)
```

How can I pass `text.var`, `ntv`, `gc.rate`, and `pos` to `parLapply` without explicitly putting them inside? (I'm guessing you pass them as a list somehow)

PS windows 7 machine so I need to use `parLapply` I think

Comment: I made a blog post on my learning with this for future searchers: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/parallelization-speed-up-functions-in-a-package/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to export those variables to the other R processes in the cluster:

```
cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", 4))
clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("text.var", "ntv", "gc.rate", "pos"))
```

Comment: @ttmaccer - how long did it take in total? Is it just that the overall time is being washed out by the variability in total time? i.e. the task wasn't really long enough for things to stabilize?

Comment: Apparently the argument `varlist` is nowadays called `list`.

Answer (score 13):

An [alternate method provided by Martin Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023403/using-parlapply-and-clusterexport-inside-a-function/12024448#12024448) would work here as well.

This method supplies the objects to each node in the cluster directly in `parLapply` call with no need to use cluster export:

```
library(parallel)
text.var <- rep("I like cake and ice cream so much!", 20)
ntv <- length(text.var)
gc.rate <- 10

pos <-  function(i) {
    paste(sapply(strsplit(tolower(i), " "), nchar), collapse=" | ")
}

cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", 4))
parLapply(cl, seq_len(ntv), function(i, pos, text.var, ntv, gc.rate) {
        x <- pos(text.var[i])
        if (i%%gc.rate==0) gc()
        return(x)
    }, pos, text.var, ntv, gc.rate
)
```

Comment: thats very helpful if you use a parLapply inside a loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
out1<-lapply(seq_len(ntv), function(i) {x <- pos(text.var[i]);if (i%%gc.rate==0) gc();return(x)})
out2<-parLapply(cl, seq_len(ntv), function(i) {x <- pos(text.var[i]);if (i%%gc.rate==0) gc();return(x)})

>     identical(out1,out2)
# [1] TRUE
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(lapply(seq_len(ntv), function(i) {x <- pos(text.var[i]);if (i%%gc.rate==0) gc();return(x)}),parLapply(cl, seq_len(ntv), function(i) {x <- pos(text.var[i]);if (i%%gc.rate==0) gc();return(x)}))


                                                                                       test
#1        lapply(seq_len(ntv), function(i) {\n    x <- pos(text.var[i])\n    if (i%%gc.rate == 0) \n        gc()\n    return(x)\n})
#2 parLapply(cl, seq_len(ntv), function(i) {\n    x <- pos(text.var[i])\n    if (i%%gc.rate == 0) \n        gc()\n    return(x)\n})
#  replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#1          100   20.03 3.453448     20.31     0.05         NA        NA
#2          100    5.80 1.000000      0.22     0.03         NA        NA

> cl
socket cluster with 2 nodes on host ‘localhost’
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you structure the code so that it's more readable and maybe add some comments?