# I'm trying to parallelize MCMC using R2Jags in R and need help solving this error

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mcmc, jags, r2jags

I want to use the `R2Jags` parallel model (`jags.parallel`) to speed up my computations.

The documentation states I need to recompile the model before updating it. However I get a clear error that I don't know how to handle.

Error message:
[image: Error message]

Code that raises error:
[image: Code that raises error]

In line 33 M[s] is used and M is defined in the data section.
What are possible reasons, that M is no longer defined when recompiling?

Cheers and thanks

Comment: A larger code snippet might help.. Could it be an environment issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790452/using-jags-parallel-from-within-a-function-r-language-error-in-getname-envir

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of plain text; most importantly, they're not accessible to non-sighted people but it makes it impossible for anyone to cut'n'paste to reproduce locally, so you're chances for getting help is significantly lowered.