# Using packages with multi-threading in R

Tags: r, multithreading

I need to multi-thread my R application as it takes 5 minutes to run and is only using 15% of the computers available CPU.

An example of a process which takes a while to run is calculating the mean of a very large raster stack containing **n** layers:

```
mean = cellStats(raster_layers[[n]], stat='sd', na.rm=TRUE)
```

Using the **parallel** library, I can create a new cluster and pass a function to it:

```
cl <- makeCluster(8, type = "SOCK")
parLapply(cl, raster_layers[[1]], mean_function)
stopCluster(cl)
```

where mean function is:

```
mean_function <- function(raster_object)
{
result = cellStats(raster_object, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE)
return(result)
}
```

This method works fine except that it can't see the 'raster' package which is required to use **cellStats**.  So it fails saying no function for **cellStats.**  I have tried including the library within the function but this doesnt help.

The raster package comes with a cluster function, and it CAN see the function cellStats, however as far as I can tell, the cluster function must return a **raster object** and must be passed a **single raster object** which isn't flexible enough for me, I need to be able to pass a list of objects and return a numeric variable... which I can do with normal clustering using the **parallel** library if only it can see the raster package functions.

So, does anybody know how I can pass a package to a node with multi-threading in R?  Or, how I can return a single value from the raster cluster function perhaps?

Comment: `export` maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019638/using-parallels-parlapply-unable-to-access-variables-within-parallel-code

Comment: That's a very useful suggestion thank you, I'll try it with a package

Comment: Perhaps use the namespace, ie `raster::cellStats`

Comment: `?clusterEvalQ` suggests using `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(raster))` to load packages on the cluster nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution came from Ben Barnes, thank you.

The following code works fine:

```
mean_function <- function(variable)
{
result = cellStats(variable, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE)
return(result)
}

cl <- makeCluster(procs, type = "SOCK")
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(raster))   
result = parLapply(cl, a_list, mean_function)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Where **procs** is the number of processors you wish to use, which must be the same value as the length of the list you are passing (in this case called **a_list**).

**a_list** in this case needs to be a list containing rasters which can be operated on to calculate the mean using the cellStats function.  So, **a_list** is simply a list of rasters, containing **procs** number of rasters.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your example, but there are some variables that I don't have access to. For example what are number_of_bands and a_list?

Comment: Specifically, I would like to use more cores to run the cellStats command on this code:

library(raster)

# make up some data
cmip <- brick(nc=150, nr=114, nl=1872)
cmip <- setValues(cmip, matrix(rep(1:17100, 1872), nc=1872))

# get mean values (area average) as data frames
cmip.mean <- as.data.frame(cellStats(cmip, mean, na.rm=T))

Comment: I have edited my answer a little to make this answer a little more intuitive

Comment: Thanks for the edit. In my case, instead of rasters I have raster bricks (a raster with several layers). Can your code still be applied in my case? I didn't get any sucess in my attempts.

Comment: Yes I would imagine so, populate the a_list with each layer of your raster brick, making sure that your procs value has the same number as the number of layers you put into the list.

Comment: It's not worth it in my case. Making a cluster with my 1872 layers takes much more time than the calculation itself. Thanks for you tips, though.