# Paraller Processing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Here, I am trying to translate the language of a text by using parallel processing in R. This is the first time I am using Parallel processing. My code is:

```
    install.packages("RYandexTranslate")
    install.packages("textcat")
    install.packages("plyr")
    install.packages("parallel")
    library("RYandexTranslate")
    library("textcat")
    library("dplyr")
    library("parallel") 
    api_key <- "trnsl.1.1.20160707T103515Z.90fa575d702ae81e.6ec78e064eb94a1c00a9bc506c615f223cf0cf5b"
    cl <- makeCluster(4) 
    Query_L_German <- c("5 euro muenze stempelglanz","2 euro muenzen uebersicht")
    Par_Conversion <- function(QUery_L_German)
    {
      for(i in 1:length(Query_L_German))
      {
        x <- translate(api_key,Query_L_German[i], "de-en")$text
        return(x)
      }
    }  
    a <- length(Query_L_German)   
    parLapply(cl, seq(a), function(i,Query_L_German,Par_Conversion)
      for(i in 1:length(Query_L_German)){
        x <- Par_Conversion(Query_L_German)
        return(x)
      }, Query_L_German, Par_Conversion)
```

But, I am getting following error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :    3 nodes produced errors; first
>   error: object 'Query_L_German' not found

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the function `parLapply` you need to define the function and variabels which are used within `parLapply` explicitly. This can be done by defining `varlist` in the the function `clusterExport`. Here is a in-depth [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019638/using-parallels-parlapply-unable-to-access-variables-within-parallel-code) on how to do this and other stuff with `parLapply` if you want to understand more.

Your example can be solved by inserting the following line before `parLapply` is used:

```
clusterExport(cl, varlist = c("api_key","Query_L_German","translate"))
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, for pointing this out. I have updated the code. Could you please look into it now

Comment: @Akshay Ok. I can reproduce it now. Please look at my edited answer. Hope it is solved now. Greetings, Daniel

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Could you please explain me how this parLapply () works. In the above code, I can use Par_Conversion function directly or using this function in parLApply() but I am not seeing any significant improvement in execution time when I use parLapply(). Is it necessary to pass list as input to this function? What is the role of 'seq()' parameter in parLapply() function?

Comment: @Akshay No Problem. To be honest the workings of `parLapply()` would be worth another question,a fter you have done some research and still have open questions. There are pretty good resources out there on the web!

Comment: @Akshay You can look up what `seq()` does by entering `?seq` and `?parLapply` into your console. It will clear things up, if you have not understood them so far. If you then have still remaining questions, it might be appropriate to post a NEW question.

Comment: @Akshay Regarding the performance. Difficult to say why you do not experience a performance speed up. Parallelization has always some sort of overhead. If your problem is not large enough (as the one in the example above), then the overhead of parallelization might be bigger then the speed up.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for all the support. I would try this on a larger set  of queries and then compare the result.